# HTML - How to show a dropdown list when a word is clicked

Tags: html

I want to do something like this:

[image]

when i click it, i want a dropdown list to show under it like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do it? hope you guys get what im trying to say. Thanks

Comment: So, How can I help you without code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various dropdown components available on internet.
You can try this as well. 
For icons you can use *Font awesome.*

*HTML code :*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Seminars <i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a>
    <a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> About</a>
    <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy you should use bootstrap library or some other that look like same and user these icons in li tag. It will give you same look and feel if you do themselves it will be too hard if you are new. I think use any third party drop-down and change the css as you want.